# What is the reason behind the build1 folder on iOS (React Native)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I did some small changes to my `info.plist` file and the app runs successfully and it's behaving as I expected after the changes. The problem is that instead of updating files under `ios/build`, after the build there was created an `ios/build1` directory, which I have not encountered before.

Why wasn't everything done under `ios/build` as usual? Am I supposed to commit this `build1` directory and the ~4600 files generated there, or is it safe to ignore it?

Comment: That's bizarre, never seen that personally in my react native history. If the application is working as expected I can't imagine it being an issue. Did you build it directly through xCode or through the CLI??

Comment: @Perniferous I built it through xCode. Very weird indeed.

Comment: Because it was generated through xCode and the project is working as expected it seems you should be able to ignore it. Have you tried deleting the build folder and cleaning the project?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It was safe to not commit files under `/ios/build1`.

I'm still not sure why the build files didn't go under `/ios/build` as usual, but I tried deleting the `build1` directory and rebuilding the project, and it didn't generate this `build1` directory again. The app still works as it should, so I guess this was just a weird XCode behavior.